# Facebook Messaging API login permissions

Tags: user-interface, facebook-chatbot

What are Item for simple chat bot developed Facebook messaging API?  My app just respond to the text message send by a Facebook user. I want to make my chatbot public but Facebook requires to add some items (permissions). Could you please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You need `manage_pages` and `pages_messaging` permissions. You also need to submit your bot for approval in the 'Messenger' tab of your app console.